# More information about the javascript .instance class property

Tags: javascript, class, documentation

I'm just learning about the existence of the `.instance` property of JS classes, which appears to return the previous instance (?) of the class.

However, I'm having trouble finding documentation about this particular property.  Searches for "javascript class .instance property" seem to be yielding information about class instances instead.

Where can I read about how this property works? Can anyone point me to good documentation?

I discovered it while researching single instance classes (singletons) from [this article](https://medium.com/@maheshkumawat_83392/node-js-design-patterns-singleton-pattern-series-1-1e0ab71e3edf).  Looks quite useful, but I would like to know the details.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `instance` property, unless you define it yourself. As for that article you're referring to, I think that can safely be ignored in its entirety, save for the last paragraph. And if you absolutely do want to make a singleton class, there are better approaches than the one described in the article, e.g. using a `static` property.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I do feel stupid now.  It's obvious the .instance property is a user-defined property.  Doh!  Thanks for pointing me toward the 'static' property!